# Distance between two circumcenters stays constant

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> As shown below, $AB<AD,BC<CD$. Prove that there exists point $E$ on $CD$ so that for any $P\ne E$ on $CD$, the distance between of $\triangle ADP$'s and $\triangle BEP$'s circumcenter stays constant.
>
> [image]

I claim that $AD\parallel BE$ defines that point $E$. Let $\triangle BEP$ intersect $AB$ at $G$.

Now $\angle ADE=\angle BEP=\angle BGP$, so $A$, $D$, $P$ and $G$ are concyclic. (This is actually $\color{blue}{\sf Reim}$ theorem used conversely)

So we may redefine the task as a generalized statement

> Given trapezoid $ADEB$ where $AD$ and $BE$ are the bases, $P$ is on $DE$. (Excluding $D$ and $E$) Prove that the distance between of $\triangle ADP$'s and $\triangle BEP$'s circumcenter stays constant.

But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Actually there's a formula $$O=\frac{\left|\begin{matrix}1&A&|A|^2\\1&B&|B|^2\\1&C&|C|^2\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix}1&A&\overline A\\1&B&\overline B\\1&C&\overline C\end{matrix}\right|}$$but I doubt it would work.

Comment: Did you confuse T and P?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. If E is the point as claimed, then $\triangle BPE$ will generate its circumcenter, M. which is unique. This in turn means OM is fixed, a constant with respect to the setup. By saying OM is constant, do you mean OM is a constant multiple of some meansure (like radius of circle ADP)?

Comment: @Moti Yes. I'll change all to $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(your second version)

Take a look at this GeoGebra animation

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/uq9kuc5s

[image]

Dragging point $P$ along line $DE$, one indeed sees that line segment $OM$ remains the same.

The proof is simple : consider the 4 perpendicular bissectors (notation "pb") $pb(AD)$, $pb(BE)$, $pb(DP)$ and $pb(EP)$ which, two by two, define the circles' centers $O$ and $M$ ; when $P$ slides along $DE$, the intersections of these perpendicular bissectors constitute a parallelogram which slides along the first two of them which are fixed, while the two others $pb(DP)$ and $pb(EP)$ preserve their distances.

Comment: Do you know any generalized method for dealing with distances between circumcenters?

Comment: There exist a very interesting framework which is the so-called "space of circles" where a circle with equation $x^2+y^2-2ax-2by+c=0$ is characterized by coordinates $(a,b,c)$, to which is attached the homogeneous quadratic form $a^2+b^2-ct$. Many properties of circles are interesting to see in this setup.

Comment: You haven't said if I have properly answered your question ?

Comment: There's no problem.